# Fill in empty blocks for each calendar month JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently able to fetch the given days of the current month as well as previous and future months using JS.  What I would like to achieve, is if say December starts on a Tuesday I would like to pass in empty objects for Sunday and Monday.  December also ends on a Thursday, so I would like to pass in empty objects for Friday and Saturday.

The code I am currently using to fetch each calendar month and display them is as follows:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [visibleMonth, setVisibleMonth] = useState(new Date().getMonth());
  const [calData, setCalData] = useState(null);
  const [dates, setDates] = useState(null);

  const getDaysArray = async (s, e) => {
    let a = [];
    for (let d = new Date(s); d <= e; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
      a.push(new Date(d).toString());
    }
    return a;
  };

  const currentMonth = useCallback(async () => {
    let d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(visibleMonth);
    let firstDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1);
    let lastDay = new Date(firstDay.getFullYear(), firstDay.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    let calendarMonth = d.toLocaleString("en-us", {
      month: "long",
      year: "numeric"
    });
    setCalData(calendarMonth);
    const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);

    setDates(dates);
  }, [visibleMonth]);

  useEffect(() => {
    currentMonth();
  }, [currentMonth]);

  const prevMonth = async () => {
    let d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(visibleMonth - 1);
    setVisibleMonth((state) => visibleMonth - 1);
    let firstDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1);
    let lastDay = new Date(firstDay.getFullYear(), firstDay.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    let calendarMonth = d.toLocaleString("en-us", {
      month: "long",
      year: "numeric"
    });
    setCalData(calendarMonth);
    const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);
    setDates(dates);
  };

  const nextMonth = async () => {
    let d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(visibleMonth + 1);
    setVisibleMonth((state) => visibleMonth + 1);

    let firstDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1);
    let lastDay = new Date(firstDay.getFullYear(), firstDay.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    let calendarMonth = d.toLocaleString("en-us", {
      month: "long",
      year: "numeric"
    });
    setCalData(calendarMonth);
    const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);
    setDates(dates);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{calData}</h1>
      <button onClick={prevMonth}>Prev Month</button>
      <button onClick={nextMonth}>Next Month</button>
      {dates &&
        dates.map((item, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{item}</div>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

the reason I am attempting to do so is due to the grid I have created.  As it stands now, every month starts at sunday and I am not successfully pairing the correct days of the month with the days on the calendar.  For example december starts on a tuesday, yet my styling shows it starts on a sunday any help would be greatly appreciated. the console logs currently show the days each month should start and end on.

Attached is a code pen for debugging! https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-visvesvaraya-r9lcw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hello again Robert - you may be over thinking this a bit. You already have what you need assuming you are going to lay this out on a grid. Assuming the first grid item in a row, let's say grid 0, is Sunday, then using `.getDay()` will return the grid placement for each day. This will work because `.getDay()` returns a zero indexed value for each day with - you guessed it; Sunday being 0. So Tuesday, 1 Dec would automatically and dynamically appear in the third grid item (or grid 2) because `.getDay()` will return 2. Hope that helps.

Comment: so would i call getDay() within the for loop?

Comment: It's difficult to answer broad questions without understanding your design. For instance, I have no idea why you're storing dates as strings - knowing that you want to do things based upon them being - well - dates (rather than strings). So I can't answer that question.

Comment: I have amended my question and sandbox to show my current styling and why I am attempting to fill in empty days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your most recent comments and updates, I recommend the following changes to the `getDaysArray()` method:

1. Create the `d` date outside the loop in order to use `getDay()` (day of week #)
2. Fill the `a[]` with empty strings with the number of day of week # in a for loop
3. Finally, populate the date strings into the remainder of the `a[]` array.

That should do it:

```js
const getDaysArray = async (s, e) => {
    let a = [];
    let d = new Date(s);
    let emptyCount = d.getDay();
    for(let i = 0; i < emptyCount; i++) {
      a.push('');
    }
    for (d; d <= e; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
      a.push(new Date(d).toString());
    }
    return a;
  };
```

Comment: you sir are a gentlemen and a scholar, you had mentioned earlier i shouldn't store the dates as a string, should I convert them to a string after I map?

Comment: Now that I've seen your intent with them they are fine. I actually advocate date formatting using strings - until the latest revisions of the Date API, it was the easiest/fastest way to accomplish it (date formatting). As you are doing. It's looking good.

Comment: thanks Randy you've helped me a lot! and I do appreciate your explanation for your logic as well

Comment: You are very welcome. Until next time :-)